# Clarifying the use of the [statistics] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag has been used more and more to refer to any question that has a quantitative element to it.

I think the tag should be used only about questions that are fundamentally *about* statistics (or probability, or sampling). Like:

- [Can we determine the percentage of statistics made up out of thin air?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/can-we-determine-the-percentage-of-statistics-made-up-out-of-thin-air)
- [Is a coin toss fair?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5982/is-a-coin-toss-fair)
- [Did the National Rifle Association (NRA) block research into statistics related to gun control?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15609/did-the-national-rifle-association-nra-block-research-into-statistics-related)
- [How accurate are the d20 dice used in role playing games?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/how-accurate-are-the-d20-dice-used-in-role-playing-games)
- [Does Gallup assume people answer honestly in their creationist vs. evolution polls?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/does-gallup-assume-people-answer-honestly-in-their-creationist-vs-evolution-pol)

These are some (what I would call) misuses of the tag:

- [Are youths that watch violent X-rated material 6 times more likely to force others sexually?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22234/are-youths-that-watch-violent-x-rated-material-6-times-more-likely-to-force-othe)
- [Does it rain more often on weekends than weekdays?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/does-it-rain-more-often-on-weekends-than-weekdays)
- [Are Fairtrade farmers paid worse than other farmers in the same regions?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22153/are-fairtrade-farmers-paid-worse-than-other-farmers-in-the-same-regions)
- [Does temperature drive CO₂?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22122/does-temperature-drive-co%E2%82%82)

Just because statistics would be useful/necessary to answer the question, that doesn't inform us at all about what the question is *about*. It seems that it is being used as a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

If we are fine with those fours question (any many others) being tagged [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics), why not:

- [Do infants have fussy periods at well-established periods after birth?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22246/do-infants-have-fussy-periods-at-well-established-periods-after-birth)
- [Do headers in football (soccer) cause brain damage?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22244/do-headers-in-football-soccer-cause-brain-damage)
- [Does drinking water after eating watermelon cause cholera?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22241/does-drinking-water-or-milk-after-eating-fish-watermelon-muskmelon-or-corn-cau)
- [Does nuclear radiation increase the risk of heart attacks?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22229/does-nuclear-radiation-increase-the-risk-of-heart-attacks)
- [Do young black males have on average higher testosterone than other races?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/do-young-black-males-have-on-average-higher-testosterone-than-other-races)

My point is that a too liberal use of [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) makes it either meaningless or a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: I suggested [burninating this tag](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/lose-the-statistics-tag), but didn't get much support.

Comment: See "[Our tags need your attention!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2793/16995)", wherein [tag:statistics] has been marked for burnination! Looks like it's underway now.

Answer (score 1):

My view may be biased here as I'm one of the top users of the [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag. But I don't think it is a meta tag or a tag that deserves destruction.

It clearly violates one of the meta-tag criteria as it works fine as a lone tag on a question that is solely about statistics.

What seems to have triggered the concern about the tag is its wide use. This, however isn't because it is a meta-tag but is because a wide variety of questions in skepticism and science can only be answered via statistical means. Perhaps it should still be used sparingly, but it should not be *abandoned*.

As an example while many questions on the [climate-change](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) and [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science) are about climate change or medical science the *controversy* is about the statistical methods used to generate particular results. Tagging them with a tag that highlights this is useful for those who want to search for such questions. Losing the tag from them won't help anyone.

In short the [statistics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) is useful if we use it carefully and we shouldn't brand it as a nasty meta-tag too readily.

Comment: "The controversy is about the statistical methods?" That's *a* controversy, maybe, but it's not "the" controversy and the questions tend to be about the issue that statistics is being used to answer, and the statistics are simply part of the evidence to be presented/assessed.

Comment: All science uses statistics. Physics? Biology? Sociology? Politics? Economics? If a tag applies indiscriminately to a large proportion of questions it's most certainly a meta tag.

Comment: @Sklivvz If we used the tag that way i would agree with you. But careful use is still possible. The majority of questions should not be so tagged, but then they never where. More discrimination: yes. Absolute blacklisting: no.

Comment: @matt_black can you not just look through the climate-change tag to find those questions?

Comment: What rule would you propose to separate questions appropriately tagged statistics from those inappropriately tagged statistics?

Comment: @matt_black we have basically no question about the branch of mathematics called statistics, but a bunch about statistic results. The second should not be tagged statistics -- that's basically the only usage we had.

Comment: @Articuno Good question. I will give it some extended thought.

Comment: @Sklivvz You argue there are **no** questions about statistics but the original post here cites at least 5 that are hard to tag as anything else. I'm going to have think about a more restrictive set of criteria to define *good* use of the tag, but I think it is already clear that your "no questions" point is wrong.

Comment: let's continue in [chat]

Answer (score 0):

The tag has been burninated and blacklisted.

Comment: Sounds good. The few that I think would have been appropriately labeled statistics can just as well be labeled probability or,  the NRA example, just left alone.